# quaint novel with a village on a plateau and the number of buttons on your clothes show your rank

Tags: story-identification

When I was in Junior High in the late 90's, I started reading a book from my teacher's mini library, she wouldn't let me keep it so I never got to finish it,
it was a fantasy novel that had yellowed a bit, and I remember thinking the cover looked outdated and tacky, so probably 80's-ish, MAYBE 70's, it was probably a young adult book though I don't think it said so anywhere on the cover...

this is what I know I remember, the heroine lives in a secluded village, nobody interacts with the outside world, people show their heirarchy with the number of buttons on their shirts or jackets, like there was some sort of caste system, the mayor or whatever would have 7 or so, everyone treats her like she knows nothing because she only has one or two buttons on her shirt, she is always pondering and thinking, she wonders what the outside world is like so she leaves... and that is where I left off! I've thought about it over and over and want to know what happens in this world!

this is what I might be remembering wrong, the village is secluded because it is on a high plateau, she left with a magical cooking pot? it could fly maybe???

I seriously doubt it was written by anyone famous or popular, it was quirky and fun, it didn't seem like a really serious work, if anyone could find it or remember the name of it I would jump for joy! please and thank you!